# Navigation for Beta Sites Pushed Down

Tags: bug, design, beta-sites

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [CSS problem - menu dislocated on a beta site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156629/css-problem-menu-dislocated-on-a-beta-site)

Whenever I visit a beta site (Raspberry Pi, Workplace, Musical Practice and Performace, etc.) the navigation ends us being pushed down below the header. Like so.

> [image: Oh Noes!]

I'm using Google Chrome 23 (Stable) 64-bit on Arch Linux.

---

**UPDATE** This happens on both the latest Chrome and Firefox on Arch Linux at all zoom levels.

Comment: Are you on normal zoom level?

Comment: @Rory Yes. Doesn't behave correctly no matter the zoom level.

Comment: @BoPersson not a duplicate if the problem persists at all zoom levels as described in comments.

Comment: @Rory: This is still a dupe of the other Beta CSS problem. If that happens at all zoom levels the other question should be re-opened.

Comment: @BryanDunsmore: Did you set the zoom level in the browser settings? Use the `search` box on the settings page to search for `page zoom`. We are not referring to the `View` menu `Zoom In` / `Zoom Out` options.

Comment: @MartijnPieters That just sets the default page zoom. The behavior is consistent across all zoom levels.

Comment: The same behavior also occurs on Firefox at all zoom levels.

Comment: @BryanDunsmore: I didn't mean Firefox, I meant Chrome.  Noone has reported this in FF (on linux) apart from you, btw.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Really weird because I can assure that it is happening on both Chrome and Firefox.